# Add Columns of Columns name during UNPIVOT

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

My Unpivot is working but I lack a Columns to put the names of the columns which were Unpivot. So far, all the data are well unpivot, I would like to add next to it the 'original' columns names.

My query ('ColumnName' is to illustrate my question, yet does nothing):

```
SELECT 'ColumnName', myData, wename, weblangue, wid FROM website
UNPIVOT
(
myData FOR names IN (sport, yahoo, mobile, di, onet, player)
) temp
```

I would like to add to each resulted rows the corresponding names: (sport, yahoo, mobile, di, onet, player)
I know that i can retrive the columns names with this query :

```
SELECT C.name FROM sys.columns c WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.website')
```

Comment: with a object named dbo.website this looks like sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to retrieve the column names, since every 6 rows it is repeated, I just have to manually add the names for every n rows :

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY w_id)%6 =1 THEN 'sport'
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY w_id)%6 =2 THEN 'yahoo'
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY w_id)%6 =3 THEN 'mobile'
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY w_id)%6 =4 THEN 'di'
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY w_id)%6 =5 THEN 'onet'
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY w_id)%6 =0 THEN 'player'
END AS Label, 
isPlayed, wename, webgue, w_id from
 website
UNPIVOT
(
 isPlayed for names in (sport, yahoo, mobile, di, onet, player)
) temp
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the new column (which you are including in your unpivot statement) called `names`) that holds the pivoted column names!.

```
SELECT names, myData, wename, weblangue, wid FROM website
UNPIVOT
(
myData FOR names IN -- You are declaring the pivoting columns names as "names" here!!!
    (sport, yahoo, mobile, di, onet, player)
) temp
```